# Refreshing contents of a narrowed org-mode buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I use emacs org-mode extensively. You can find my full set-up at https://github.com/ehuang3/dotfiles.

The problem is as such:

When I do `org-capture-refile` and return to my `org-agenda-view` the new task does not show up in my project restricted view unless I also run `bh/narrow-to-project` (which is defined [here](https://github.com/ehuang3/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs.d/org-norang.el#L1229)).

```
(defun bh/narrow-to-project ()
  (interactive)
  (if (equal major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
      (progn
        (org-with-point-at (bh/get-pom-from-agenda-restriction-or-point)
          (bh/narrow-to-org-project)
          (save-excursion
            (bh/find-project-task)
            (org-agenda-set-restriction-lock)))
        (org-agenda-redo)
        (beginning-of-buffer))
    (bh/narrow-to-org-project)
    (save-restriction
      (org-agenda-set-restriction-lock))))
```

My current solution is to define the following hook

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-after-finalize-hook 'bh/narrow-to-project)
```

However, this leaves something to be desired as running `org-capture` will also narrow to project. If possible, I'd like to stay in the `wide` view when I'm in `wide` and refresh the `narrow` view when I'm restricted to a project.

My `lisp` is not strong enough to tease out and reproduce how `bh/narrow-to-project` manages to refresh the restricted `agenda-view` correctly. I know `bh/narrow-to-org-project` has a call to `widen` which I think enables `org-agenda-redo` to refresh correctly with the new task.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered generating an org-agenda view that displays only what you need, instead of trying to narrow / widen it?  You can even create your own org-agenda skip function to better isolate your *project*.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Special-agenda-views.html ; and, see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html

Comment: You may also wish to consider using `org-tags-view` and/or `org-search-view` to display only what you need in the org-agenda buffer instead of narrowing / widening it.  See:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  Your project can use special keywords, or special tags, etc. to help identify it in a particular search.

Comment: I am using a highly customized org-mode adopted from http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html. I already have a custom agenda, and I operate at the level of subtrees to display what I need. I just can't figure out how to fix this refresh thing...